# Java crontab (Ubuntu)

Tags: java, cron

Having issues in setting up a Java crontab to run every 1 minute. New to this - have tried a few things though, appreciate any pointers

1. Java class runs on Ubuntu command without any issues 
   (Have updated CLASSPATH in bashrc for the dependent libraries etc.)
2. crontab -e 
   */1 * * * * root (cd /usr/share/java; java packagename.class)

Answer (score -1):

You can execute this script from anywhere. (That's because of the absolute paths)

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/share/java;$PATH
java -cp /your/path a.b.c.ClassName &>/your/path/to/output
```